# ant still throwing error "cannot find python" after setting the PATH variable

Tags: python-2.7, ant

I included the path of the python msi in the PATH environment variable and have the "exec" in the build file also correctly delineated.
I am still getting the error -

```
BUILD FAILED
F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor\build.xml:16: The following error occu
rred while executing this line:
F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor\build-common.xml:284: The following er
ror occurred while executing this line:
F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor\blocklyeditor\build.xml:50: Execute fa
iled: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python" (in directory "F:\GitHub\
appinventor-sources\appinventor\blocklyeditor"): CreateProcess error=2, The syst
em cannot find the file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1047)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:617)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.launcher.Java13CommandLauncher.exec(Jav
a13CommandLauncher.java:58)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.launch(Execute.java:428)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Execute.execute(Execute.java:442)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:628)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
CheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(Single
CheckExecutor.java:38)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find th
e file specified
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:385)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:136)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1028)
        ... 48 more

Total time: 20 seconds
F:\GitHub\appinventor-sources\appinventor [master +2 ~0 -0 !]>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: You're missing the ANT code that throws the error. Based on experience this is mostly because you haven't specified the pull path the python binary. Also the use of environment variables is ANT is quirky and sometimes people get it wrong (an example would establish this) and finally using environment variables is a bad idea IMHO makes the build fragile and not stand-alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the path of the python msi in the PATH

It shouldn't be the path to the msi, but the path to the exe. (So you should run the msi first yourself, in order to install python).

```
$ python --version
sh.exe": python: command not found

$ PATH=$PATH:/c/Python27/

$ python --version
Python 2.7.6
```